# How should I customize my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, sdk, fbml, facebook-page

Okey, so I have a business Facebook Page like many others. And I want to customize it like many others have. But Facebook (henceforth FB) documentation is really bad.

So I go and edit my page and there I find Facebook Static FBML application. So far, great, and I can even use standard HTML to edit it. And then there is also FBML which I can use to make more advanced customization, like show something for people who "Like" and something else for others. Pretty straightforward. But then i notice that Facebook is deprecating FBML and recommend me to use JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins.

So what does this mean for me? Can I customize my site this way or not?

The documentation for JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins is worthless and very general, how do these apply for my Page customization?

But Facebook Static FBML application it self is an application i guess. Will it work in the future?

What is the best way to customize my FB Page and add tabs and so on?
What should I do?

Comment: http://www.eleen.com/2009/08/add-custom-tabs-to-your-facebook-business-page/

Comment: Thanks for trying, but how was that help full? I allready know about FBML and I seem to know something you do not, they are stopping it.

Comment: @calvinf how is JavaScript SDK not related to the tag javascript? :P

Comment: The question has little to do with JavaScript and a lot to do with specific knowledge about Facebook's tools and SDKs.  I'd also suggest focusing on one question -- you've asked six here so it's hard for people reading it to know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER (for lazy people):**
While Facebook Static FBML application might be working in the near future, it seems like building applications yourself is the right way to go.

Build an application: http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php

Also you do not need the FBML since you can do all that is needed with the graph-api.

Graph-API doc: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Also, by using the iframe canvas when building apps this allows you to host your page tabs where ever you want allowing you do use any coding language you want.